# Entity Framework multiple parent tables

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008, entity-framework

I have an existing database that I am trying to access via Entity Framework 4.3. Most tables and relationships haven't been a problem, but this set of tables is causing me a few issues which I can't seem to find an answer to.

Here are the (condensed) entities:

**Customer**

```
public class Customer
{
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    private int addressSourceTypeID = 2;
    [NotMapped]
    public int AddressSourceTypeID { 
        get { return addressSourceTypeID; } 
        set { addressSourceTypeID = value; } }

    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Contract> Contracts { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}
```

**Contract**

```
public class Contract
{
    public int ContractID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    private int addressSourceTypeID = 4;
    [NotMapped]
    public int AddressSourceTypeID { 
        get { return addressSourceTypeID; } 
        set { addressSourceTypeID = value; } }

    public virtual int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }

    //public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}
```

**Address**

```
public class Address
{
    [Key]
    public int AddressID { get; set; }
    public int AddressSourceTypeID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Customer")]
    public int SourceKey { get; set; }

    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
    //public virtual Contract Contract { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
}
```

What I have above is two entities `Customer` and `Contract` that both can have child `Address` entities. Currently the `Address` entity is set up to be a child of the `Customer` entity and this works fine as there isn't a link to `Contract` from `Address`.

I have tried adding in `Contract` to the `Address` entity as I have done with the `Customer` entity as you can see from the commented out code segments. Unfortunatly this doesn't work, but I'm not surprised due to the reference to `Customer` in the `Address` ForeignKey annotation. I even tried to create specific version of the `Address` entity (i.e. `CustomerAddress`), but I get an error when more than one entity is attempting to bind to the same table.

I have also tried using `ModelBuilder` in the EF `DBContext` however my knowledge here is pretty limited and I'm not sure how to do it in this case.

Overall, what I need is the following:

- Customer entity to have a collection of child Addresses.
- Contract entity to have a collection of child Addresses.

The link between these 'parent' tables to the Address table uses the following:

- Customer: CustomerID => Address: SourceKey AND Customer: AddressSourceTypeID (always 2) => Address: AddressSourceTypeID.
- Contract: ContractID => Address: SourceKey AND Contract: AddressSourceTypeID (always 4) => Address: AddressSourceTypeID.

If anyone could help me or point me in the correct direction that would be great.

Thanks very much.

Comment: The `SourceKey` column in the `Address` table in the database is the foreign key for *both* one-to-many relationships??? That is technically allowed and you could use two `[ForeignKey]` annotations on `SourceKey` for the `Customer` and the `Contract` navigation property. But it would mean that whenever an `Address` refers to a `Customer` "1234" through the `SourceKey` FK there also must be a `Contract` "1234" and vice versa - which is hard to imagine because `Customer` and `Contract` are related by a one-to-many relationship and your keys look like autogenerated identities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either have EF enforce your `SourceKey` attribute using Table per Hierarchy Inheritance - and then you're mapping will break, or you can enforce the `SourceKey` in your business logic and only have EF manage the main `Address` class.

If you have to maintain your current DB schema, I think having your business logic enforce your `SourceKey` as a disriminator is your only option:

```
public class Address
{
    public int AddressID { get; set; }
    public int AddressSourceTypeID { get; set; }
    public int SourceKey { get; set; }
    public virtual Contract Contract { get; set; }
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
public class Contract
{
    public Contract()
    {
        this.Addresses = new List<Address>();
    }

    public int ContractID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}
public class Customer
{
    public Customer()
    {
        this.Addresses = new List<Address>();
    }

    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}
```

And this in your fluent mappings:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Address>().HasOptional(t => t.Contract)
            .WithMany(t => t.Addresses)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.SourceKey);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Address>().HasOptional(t => t.Customer)
            .WithMany(t => t.Addresses)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.SourceKey);
```

Alternatively - if you created a `CustomerAddress` and `ContractAddress`, you can using TPH inheritance enforce the `SourceKey` - but currently there's no way to map the Nav properties:

```
public abstract class Address
{
    [Key]
    public int AddressID { get; set; }
    public int AddressSourceTypeID { get; set; }

    public int SourceKey { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerAddress : Address
{
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
}

public class ContractAddress : Address
{
    public virtual Contract Contract { get; set; }
}
```

And this as your mapping:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Address>()
            .Map<ContractAddress>(m => m.Requires("AddressSourceTypeID").HasValue(2))
            .Map<CustomerAddress>(m => m.Requires("AddressSourceTypeID").HasValue(4));
```

This will enforce `AddressSourceTypeID` as your discriminator - unfortunately the breakdown here is in mapping your nav property back to the ContractAddress and Customer Address.  See [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11949742/entity-framework-multitenant-shared-data-architecture-single-column-multiple-f/12065892#12065892) which had the same basic problem.  Maybe this will start you in the right direction at least.

Comment: Worked almost 100%, the only issue I had was that I needed to make `SourceKey` nullable. Thanks very much.

Comment: Unfortunately, using this still creates constraints in efcore3.1 maybe because optional is not available. As soon as I tried to add a sourcekey not found in the first entity associated, the constraint kicks in.