# EF Code First Single foreign key to multiple parents

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Hope you can help

I have 3 (and more to come) tables `[Customer] [Order]` and `[Invoice]`.

All of these tables have an ID column `[ID - Guid]`.

I have a table `[Notes]` and it is comprised of 2 columns (for brevity): -

```
[ID - Guid]
[ParentFKID - Guid]
[Comment - String]
```

I wish to create a collection of `[Notes]` on each of the 3 (and more to come) "parent" entities and configure each of these entities to populate the collection from the `[Notes]` table where the primary key of the parent table in question is pointing to the `[ParentFKID]` column.

So essentially the column `[ParentFKID]` is a foreign key, but a foreign key to multiple other tables. This is possible as we are using GUID keys.

This is essentially so we don't have replicated tables of `[CustomerNotes] [OrderNotes]` and `[InvoiceNotes]` AND ALSO to avoid the other alternative of having the notes table forever growing with the foreign keys `[Customer_ID] [Order_ID]` and `[Invoice_ID]`

Surely there must be a way to cater for this with a Fluent API mapping but as I'm so new to EF Code First and the Fluent API then I'm struggling to see it.

I don't care that the constraints may be unavailable - this is preferable anyway and seemingly impossible with the structure. This surely is a common scenario.

Can anyone help and provide an example of how to configure the entities for the model to enable this scenario ?

Comment: Your solution may be common, but that doesn't make it any less smelly and poor.  I suggest you read items #1 and #4 of this https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/five-simple--database-design-errors-you-should-avoid/  Consider that your notes table may grow 3x as fast as individual tables.. reducing performance of all notes lookups.  Also, there is no enforcement of unique constraint.. you may be using GUID's, that doesn't mean that your app (or human error) can't insert the same guid in multiple tables though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this mapping with Fluent API:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
    .HasMany(c => c.Notes)
    .WithRequired()
    .HasForeignKey(n => n.ParentFKID);

modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
    .HasMany(o => o.Notes)
    .WithRequired()
    .HasForeignKey(n => n.ParentFKID);

modelBuilder.Entity<Invoice>()
    .HasMany(i => i.Notes)
    .WithRequired()
    .HasForeignKey(n => n.ParentFKID);
```

I expect here that `ParentFKID` is a *property* for the FK in your `Note` class. <strike>If you don't want that replace `HasForeignKey` by: `.Map(m => m.MapKey("ParentFKID"));`</strike>

---

**Edit**

Using independent associations (i.e. using `MapKey` without a FK property in the `Note` class) with a shared FK column does not work and throws exceptions when the mapping is defined.

---

Keep in mind that if you are going to *create* the database schema with Code-First EF will enforce all the FK constraints. You have to disable that manually in the database then (or maybe it's also possible with a code-based customized migration, but I don't know if and how).

I also expected that the `ParentFKID` column is not nullable (hence `WithRequired`) because, I guess, a note without a parent doesn't make sense.

I would suggest to avoid having navigation properties to the parent - customer, order and invoice - in the `Note` class. If you would attempt to load a note including its parent - and you had to include all three possible parent navigation properties because you can't know from a given note which type the parent has - EF will create `INNER JOIN` queries (due to the required relationship and because it expects that the constraint is enforced) and this will return no result, even not the parent. (You could possibly hack around the `INNER JOIN` by using `WithOptional` instead of `WithRequired` - despite of the FK not allowing `NULL` values. EF would create a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` then when eager loading the parents.)

I'm really not sure if all that will work and doesn't have unwished side effects. Although you are saying it's a common scenario EF does not have explicit support for relationships without enforced constraints.

A scenario which EF would support better is having a base entity `EntityWithNotes` that carries the `Notes` collection and which `Customer`, `Order` and `Invoice` derive from. You would define only a single relationship between `EntityWithNotes` and `Note`. On database side you have the choice to put `Customer`, `Order` and `Invoice` into a single table (Table-Per-Hierarchy (TPH) mapping) which honestly sounds ridiculous considering how different the business meaning of those entities is. I wouldn't even think about it. Or you put `Customer`, `Order`, `Invoice` **and** `EntityWithNotes` into different tables (Table-Per-Type (TPT) mapping). But then, TPT is not really known for the best performance. I wouldn't really consider this for such important entities and probably fast growing tables.

**Edit**

While the mapping with shared a FK property like shown at the beginning works I get other exceptions when I remove the enforcement of the foreign key constraints in the database. Although I can save data successfully I get exceptions about inconsistent states of the `ObjectContext` because apparently the context always expects that the constraints are enforced.

I would suggest to stay away from this model and use separate tables for `CustomerNotes`, `OrderNotes` and `InvoiceNotes`. If that isn't possible (existing and unchangable database schema?) it is questionable if Entity Framework is an appropriate tool for such a schema.

Comment: Interesting. [As you may remember](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13953675/861716) I've had a lot of struggles with these _polymorphic associations_. After much pondering I currently lean to creating separate child tables for each parent. I also doubt "whether all that will work", I'm afraid EF is going to grumble about the shared foreign key, but I'll have to try sometime this weekend.

Comment: @GertArnold: I intended to make the `EntityWithNotes` in my last paragraph a real entity (with its own DbSet for example), not just a base for the other three entities. I believe it would work then if the `Notes` collection is in that base entity and the FK in `Note` is refering directly to it, not to the other three entities. I think it's not a situation of polymorphic associations then. I'm also not quite sure about the shared FK. A shared navigation property won't work for sure, but a shared FK... my careful tip: It works :) (I'll test it tomorrow.)

Comment: @GertArnold: My tip was only 50% correct: The shared FK works with foreign key associations (`HasForeignKey`) but it doesn't for independent associations (`MapKey`) which is a bit weird but using `MapKey` three times with the same column name was throwing an exception about ambiguous names. Anyway, the real problem is removing the constraint enforcement in the database which led to other exceptions (see Edit above) I couldn't really escape from.

Comment: Weekend turned out busier than expected... glad you had time to test this. I agree with your final conclusion. The idea of a base class does not appeal to me either. The only problem with three separate tables is that it gets harder to fetch notes irrespective of owner, but that could be tackled by a (UNION) view in the database.