# Equivalent of Polymorphic association from Ruby on Rails in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, ruby-on-rails, entity-framework, polymorphic-associations

In my asp app I want to use something like  [Polymorphic association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations) from Ruby on Rails' Active record in Entity Framework.
I know there are some topics already on StackOverflow discussing this, but I want to achieve it without using of inheritance as it is able in ruby on rails, so I want to ask if it is possible.

Thank you.

Comment: "I want to achieve it without using of inheritance as it is able in ruby on rails" - What exactly do you mean by that? It's not clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby on Rails implements this pattern by defining a **type** and a **key** column. As it says in the link you quote:

> To make this work, you need to declare both a foreign key column and a type column in the model that declares the polymorphic interface

In a canonical relational database this can never be implemented as a foreign key constraint, because one foreign key field can only refer to one primary key field. So a polymorphic association in RoR probably implemented merely as a "soft" foreign key.

That's the reason why this can't be done in EF exactly as it is done in RoR. Same as a foreign key, an association can only refer to one other entity. However, you can create inherited classes, each of which can refer to their own entity. That's why you will only find examples of inheritance when these associations are implemented with EF. Another example is my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13953675/861716).

Comment: Thank you @Gert for your answer, I thought that it we be like you said, but I wanted to give it a try. In my case I am not able to create inherited classes, because those two existing classes have nothing in common or just a little bit and introducing of inheritance would break the other parts of my application, so I will probably go by way of two optional foreign Keys, while one of them will be null and the other will point to object and vice versa

Answer (score 2):

I have a lot of experience of doing proper polymorphic associations (i.e. associations defined by an interface, not by an abstract type) using Entity Framework.  I think this pattern is essential for good object modelling, and I have berated the EF development team several times about the lack of native support for this pattern which could easily be added, IMO. (Native support would include the ability to query those associations in LINQ to Entites, just as you can in LINQ To Objects).

In my implementations, you have to hold a 'compound key' that defines the type and the identity of the associated objects  -  which, I believe, is how it is done in both Hibernate and RoR.  Navigating the relationship is done in code, by reading this key and then dynamically creating a method for accessing instances of the corresponding type.

Although you cannot make this compound key an FK, you can add referential integrity with a bit more effort using the 'table of two halves pattern'.  I have written this up in some detail in the Naked Objects Development manual, which you can look up on Git Hub.  The patterns do not depend upon the Naked Objects Framework, however, and you could replicate them.  All the source is there (see the class PolymorphicNavigator in NakedObjects.Helpers).

Answer (score 0):

Further to @richard-pawson's answer, I've ported the "table-of-two-halves" pattern from Entity Framework to Java (JDO/DataNucleus), with a complete example up on [github](https://github.com/isisaddons/isis-module-poly).

You should be able to use it to come up with something similar back in .NET land.