# Entity Framework - Allow multiple classes to have a list of items with the same class type

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm pretty new to entity framework and not an expert on database architecture, so I'm struggling to know what terms to Google for the question I have.

Say I have various entities, like Joke, Image, Story, Cartoon. They all have different data, but they share the fact that they all  have an Id. In my case, a Guid.

I want to have an entity called Comment which just stores the comment, the user who made the comment, and  the Id of the item commented on - which can be any  of the types above. I don't want to have to create a JokeComments table, ImageComments, StoryComments etc. - because that seems inefficient - having to maintain many classes for every 'commentable' item, and means that I can't easily just grab all comments  from a single  User.

So I have something like this

```
public abstract class IdentifiableObject
{
    public IdentifiableObject()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    }

    public Guid Id { get; set; }   
}

public class Joke: IdentifiableObject
{ 
    public List<Comment> Comments {get; set;}
}

public class  Story : IdentifiableObject
{
    public List<Comment> Comments {get; set;}
}

public class Comment
{
     public Guid Id {get; set;}
     public String Comment {get; set;}
     [Key, ForeignKey ("IdentifiableObject")]
     public Guid TargetId {get; set;}
}
```

But this doesn't work, and I have no idea where to start Googling. I've read about using Interfaces, but I  couldn't work out how that would work in this situation. Do I need to add a 'TargetType' property in the Comment class? If so, what would the type be? If I leave out any key in the Comment class, it creates a FK for every type it can be associaated with, which leaves me with the problem of knowing how to retrieve the  target.

Can anyone explain to me how I would approach this requirement  in EntityFramework, or just let me know what the name  of what I am trying to do is, to help point me in the right direction on Google?  Thanks..

Comment: This is [not trivial](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13953675/861716).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a great or direct answer to your question, but you can create a base class with the comments property, and it'll work;

```
public abstract class CommentedObject
{ 
    public List<Comment> Comments {get; set;}

public class Joke: CommentedObject
{ 
}

public class  Story : CommentedObject
{
}

public class Comment
{
     public Guid Id {get; set;}
     public String Comment {get; set;}
     [Key, ForeignKey ("IdentifiableObject")]
     public Guid TargetId {get; set;}
}
```

It's nasty, in that it involves inheritance to solve the problem, but it works.

You might want to read about the [EF table per hierarchy](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=table+per+hierarchy+code+first) and [table per type](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=table+per+type+code+first) strategies.

Comment: Thanks Steve - this is the way to go. Base class for all of the related types, with TablePerType. It looks like EF will understand that pattern.